# Mobile Menu category link is undefined URL can't working in Magento 2​

Tags: url, magento2.3.3, redirect-url, mobile-menu, undefined

I'm facing some annoying issues. When I'm on the desktop, no problem with the menu link.

When I'm on responsive, when I go through the menu, I have the right URL but
when I click on category link the item, I'm redirected to a 404 page ( my.domain/undefined) And undefined URL.

If any custom script and tool and module so give me the link 
so I sorted this issue fast ASAP.

I used the module but can't work 
https://github.com/olegkoval/magento2-regenerate_url_rewrites

If any idea how can I sort this issue please give me 
solution ASAP and any custom script for that?

Thank you.